# What is difference between segment, Volume and Partition ?(In Storage Domain)

Tags: dns, storage

I have a basic question related to storage domain. Can any one answer what is difference between segment, Volume and Partition ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partition is a division of a storage device described in the partition map, which may contain a volume. A volume comprises the bytes that contain a filesystem.

An unpartitioned device, such as a floppy, contains a volume but does not contain a partition.

I've never heard of "segment." Google gives http://evms.sourceforge.net/terminology.html, which defines that as any logically contiguous range of sectors.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify @Potatoswatter regarding segments:

- In disk drives these are called (track) sectors. Typically 4096-byte (4 KB) size, known as the Advanced Format.
- In memory, segments (or sections) are divided parts of the primary memory. References to memory locations can then be broken down into: segment id, segment offset.